# while loop not cycling through as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a loop that runs through returned rows from a MySQL query and performs commands.

When the data is displayed on the webpage (seen at the end of the pasted code), the requested_date (from the $result_dec query) is cycling through correctly, but the memPayout(from the $emailcompleted query) is not.  Where it shows the memPayout it is just listing the same number for each date.

When I run this in phpmyadmin, I see that different dates have different memPayouts..so I know there is a bug here.

I appreciate the help.

UPDATE: I've updated the old code with the new one that I adjusted.  I tried to wrap the email earnings query with the original foreach.  I also removed the unnecessary extra bgcolor switch.  The result on my webpage is still the same as before.  Any more advice is really appreciated.

```
<?php                           
//--------------------- Code for Decline TRANSACTION --------------------------------------
$u_id = $_SESSION['user_ses']['id'];

$result_dec = @mysql_query("(select trv.tr_user_id , usr.full_name ,usr.email , usr.paypal ,  trv.requested_date, trv.requested_status, trv.click_payment_status, trv.tracking_id
from  tbl_trackvalue as trv ,tbl_tracking as t , tbl_offers as off , tblusers as usr
where t.id=trv.tracking_id  and off.id=t.offer_id and  usr.id=trv.tr_user_id and usr.id='1454' 
and trv.payment_status='pending' and trv.requested_status='declined'  group by trv.tr_user_id, trv.requested_date order by trv.requested_date asc )
union all
(select trv.tr_user_id , usr.full_name ,usr.email , usr.paypal , trv.click_request_date, trv.requested_status, trv.click_payment_status, trv.tracking_id
from  tbl_trackvalue as trv ,tbl_tracking as t , tbl_offers as off , tblusers as usr
where t.id=trv.tracking_id  and off.id=t.offer_id and  usr.id=trv.tr_user_id and usr.id='1454' 
and trv.payment_status='pending' and trv.click_payment_status='declined'  group by trv.tr_user_id, trv.click_request_date order by trv.requested_date asc ) ");
    $nr = mysql_num_rows($result_dec);
    $categories_d = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_dec))
    { 
            $categories_d[] = $row;
    }

    if(count($categories_d)>0)
    {
        $counter=0;
        foreach($categories_d as $index=>$rec)
        {
            $counter++;
            if ($counter % 2 == 0)
            {
                    $bgcolor = "#FFFFFF";
            }
            else
            {
                    $bgcolor = "#F5F7D9";
            }



        $userId=$rec['tr_user_id'];

  $EmailCompletedOffer=@mysql_query("select off.member_amount as memPayout
                        from  tbl_trackvalue as trv ,tbl_tracking as t , tbl_offers as off , tblusers as usr 
                        where t.id=trv.tracking_id  and off.id=t.offer_id and  off.offer_type='mailchimp' and  usr.id=trv.tr_user_id and 
                        trv.tr_user_id=$userId and trv.requested_date='".$requested_date."' and trv.payment_status='pending' and trv.total_conversion !=0 and trv.requested_status='declined' ");
                        $rowemailEarn=@mysql_fetch_array($EmailCompletedOffer);
                        $totalEmailEarnAmount1=$rowemailEarn['memPayout'];

?>
                        <div class="datarow_his">
                            <div class="his_onecol1"><?php echo '$'. $totalEmailEarnAmount1;?> </div>
                            <div class="his_onecol1"> <?php echo "Declined"; ?> </div>
                            <div class="his_onecol2"><?php echo date("M j,Y " ,strtotime($rec['requested_date']));?></div>
                            <!--<div class="his_onecol1"><?php //echo date("M j,Y " ,strtotime($rec['paid_date']));?></div>-->
                        </div> 
                        <p><?php echo $totalEmailEarnAmount1?></p>
<?php                    /*}
                    } */




        } 
    } 

?>
```

Comment: I know it's a lot.  I'm just terribly stuck and have been working at this for hours.  I'm a newbie and this one is throwing me for a loop (pun intended).

Comment: Please post it more clear,  simplified and specific to the point. Is overwhelming.

Comment: It`s also recommended to use alias when joining tables.

Comment: Thanks. Any advice on the new code I just updated.  I made some of the changes, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code roughly looks like this:

```
fetch categories
if(categories not empty) {
  foreach(category) {
    set $bgcolor and $userId (has no effect)
  }
  get query results for the last $userID and set $totalEmailEarnAmount1
  if(categories not empty) {
    foreach(category) {
      set $bgcolor again (has no effect)
      generate a div using $totalEmailEarnAmount1
    }
  }
}
```

Since you set $totalEmailEarnAmount1 outside the final `foreach`, it has the same value on every iteration of the loop.

(If you indent your code in a way that is consistent with its structure, errors like this will become obvious. The messy indentation makes it hard for you to see what is going on.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  So I need to somehow combine the two foreach loops?

Comment: Right now you are making only one query, for whatever value $userID has after the first loop. You probably want to make a query for every user. So, the query should be in the loop. You might still need multiple loops if you want to display data in several different blocks, but then you would store the data in an array and display it later.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help.  I will think through this.

Comment: I don't want to make a query for every user here.  This will display a payment history on a specific users member page.  I see what you mean about the email earnings code not being part of any loop.  Obviously it's not going to cycle through that way :)  Thanks for the help.